# I have a requirement to validate email address and confirm in next page as <first letter>xxxxx@<domain first letter>xxxx.com

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts

User will enter email address and click on validate button. and after validation,in next page the email address will be shown as **first letter of emailxxxxxxxx(till @ symbol)@domain's first letter namexxxx(till domain name length).com**. xxxxx represents the length of name

here i'm able to validate the email address using java regx but not able to display the patterns as mentioned above. any idea to achieve in java. I'm very new to this,for any mistake,excuse me

Comment: post your code, what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

As your description is very vague about the requirements. This might be a starting point for you.

```
String emailAddress = "john.doe@example.com";
String secretAddress = emailAddress.replaceAll("(.{4}).*@(.{4}).*(\\..*)", "$1xxxxxxxx@$2xxxx$3");
System.out.println(secretAddress);
```

output

```
johnxxxxxxxx@examxxxx.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript in JSP page itself like

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "deepak.kumar@gmail.com";
    var res = str.substring(0, indexOf("@");
   var res2= str.substring(str.indexOf("@")+1, str.length);
}
</script>
```

OutPUT: res=deepak.kumar
res2=gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
String yourEmail = "anewemail@gmail.com"; // any email id
String[] splitString = yourEmail.split("@");

firstLetter = String.valueOf(splitString[0].charAt(0));
String[] secondPart = splitString[1].split(".com");
String finalAnswer = firstLetter+"xxxxxx"+"@"+ secondPart[0].charAt(0)+"xxx.com";
```